# Number of real roots of a quintic equation

Tags: general-topology, roots, connectedness, quintics

> Find the number of connected components of the set $$\left\{x\in \mathbb R : x^3\left(x^2+5x-\frac{65}{3}\right)>70x^2-300x-297\right\}$$ under the usual topology on $\mathbb R$.

We solve the equation $\displaystyle x^3\left(x^2+5x-\frac{65}{3}\right)-70x^2+300x+297=0$ and the real roots we get give the partion for the real line into intervals. We then check the for the intervals satisfying the condition given in the set which will give the number of connected components.

I could not explicitly calculate the roots nor determine the precisely number of real roots. Is there a way to solve this as it is a question in a math examination ? Can we solve this by Descartes' rule of signs ?? I am aware this question has already been asked.

Using Descarte's rule of sign we see that the polynomial can have $2$ or $0$ positive real roots and $3$ or $1$ negative real roots.

Comment: "I am aware this question has already been asked." Then I am puzzled as to why you are asking it again. If the question was previously asked here, can you include a link to that previous appearance, please? Are you referring to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2630872/number-of-real-roots-of-a-quintic-polynomial ? or maybe https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300195/real-roots-of-a-quintic-polynomial ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2927694/number-of-connected-components-of-a-set

Comment: @GerryMyerson "Find the number of components..." was in fact asked in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2927694/number-of-connected-components-of-a-set. However, I believe the present question has a different focus: If you do not know the real roots, which methods can be used to determine at least their number? In particular, does Descartes' rule of signs provide an answer?

Comment: Descarte's rule of signs only provides an upper bound for the number of positive or negative real roots....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descartes's rule of sign will not give you the exact number as you have shown in your question. Here are some other methods that can be applied to a polynomial $p(x)$.

1) Check whether there are multiple (real or complex) roots. A root $a$ of $p(x)$ is a multiple root $a$ if and only if $a$ is a common root of $p(x), p'(x)$. To see this, write $p(x) = (x-a)^nq(x)$ with $n \ge 1$ and $q(a) \ne 0$. Then $p'(x) = n(x-a)^{n-1}q(x) + (x-a)^nq'(x)$. If $n > 1$, then $p'(a) = 0$ and if $n = 1$ then $p'(a) \ne 0$. We conclude that $p(x)$ has a multiple root if and only if the gcd of $p(x)$ and $p'(x)$ (which can easily be computed by the Euclidean algorithm) has degree $\ge 1$. In fact, if $p(x)$ has a root of $a$ of order $n > 1$, then $(x-a)^{n-1}$ divides $p(x), p'(x)$. Conversely, assume that the gcd $h(x)$ has degree $\ge 1$. Then $h(x)$ has a root $a$ and we see that $p(a) = p'(a) = 0$.

Applying this to your polynomial $p(x) = x^5+5x^4-\frac{65}{3}x^3-70x^2 +300x +297$ shows that no multiple roots exist. Hence it has $1$ or $3$ aor $5$ real roots of order $1$ (since non-real roots occur in complex conjugate pairs).

2) Consider $p'(x), p''(x),p'''(x)$ to find extrema and inflection points. This allows you to determine roots of $p(x)$ lying between these points.

Doing this with your polymomial yields $p'(x) = 5x^4+20x^3-65x^2-140x+300 = 5(x^4+4x^3-13x^2-28x+60)$, $p''(x) = 20x^3+60x^2-130x-140 = 10(2x^3+6x^2-13x-14)$, $p'''(x) = 60x^2+120x-130 = 10(6x^2-12x-13)$. It is easy to verify that $p'(x)$ has the roots $-5,-3,2$, where $2$ has order $2$ (try the divisors of $60$). We have $p''(-5) = -21 < 0$, $p''(-3) = 53 > 0$, $p''(2) = 0$, $p'''(2) = 250 \ne 0$. Hence $p(x)$ has a local maxinum at $-5$, a local minimum at $-3$ and an inflection point at $2$. Hence $p(x)$ is increasing on $(-\infty,-5]$, decreasing on $[-5,-3]$ and increasing on $[-3,\infty)$. We have $p(-5) = -\frac{734}{3}$, $p(-3) =  -486$. Hence $p(x)$ does not have a root in $(-\infty,-3]$ and a single root of order $1$ n $[-3,\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you @Paul Frost for the detailed answer. This is extremely helpful.

Comment: How can we deal with the no. Of roots to solve this question @YadatiKiran. Can you give a brief explanation.

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana: I suppose it has been well explained above. Read part (2).

Comment: No not that I mean to solve the original question no. Of connected components @YadatiKiran

Comment: So since we have a root in $[-3,\infty)$ we get two intervals $(-\infty,-3)$ and $(-3,\infty)$. The constraint given in the question is $x^5+5x^4-\frac{65}{3}x^3-70x^2 +300x +297>0$. So check for values of $x$ in the two intervals which satisfy the constraint.

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana The general approach is this: We are given a polynomial $p(x)$  and want to determine the number of connected components of the set on which $p(x) > 0$. To do so, we have to determine all real roots $x_1 < \dots < x_k$ of $p(x)$ (it is possible that there are **no**, in which case it suffices to check the sign of $p(0)$).  Then on each of the open intervals $(-\infty,x_1), (x_1,x_2),\dots,(x_{k-1},x_k), (x_k,\infty)$ we have either $p(x) > 0$ or $p(x) < 0$, and this can be easily checked. The number of intervals on which $p(x) > 0$ gives the answer.

Comment: @Paulfrost thank you very much that was a real help